# Не понятная ошибка TorSharp

Tags: c#, tor

Есть два метода которые я использую, и если я вызываю второй раз его прегрузку то выдает ошибку, ошибку напишу ниже
Вот код методов

```
  public async Task<string> GetSourceByPageIdforTor(int id)
    {
        string currentUrl = url.Replace("{CurrentId}", id.ToString());

        var settings = new TorSharpSettings
        {
            ZippedToolsDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "TorZipped"),
            ExtractedToolsDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "TorExtracted"),
            PrivoxyPort = 1337,
            TorSocksPort = 1338,
            TorControlPort = 1339,
            TorControlPassword = "",
            ToolRunnerType = ToolRunnerType.VirtualDesktop,
            TorStrictNodes = false,
            ReloadTools = false,
            //  EnableSecurityProtocolsForFetcher= false

        };

        // download tools
        await new TorSharpToolFetcher(settings, new HttpClient()).FetchAsync();

        // execute
        var proxy = new TorSharpProxy(settings);
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://localhost:" + settings.PrivoxyPort))
        };
        await proxy.ConfigureAndStartAsync();
        //  await proxy.GetNewIdentityAsync();

        var configuration = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader()
            .WithRequesters(handler)
            .WithCss()
            .WithJavaScript();

        var _context = BrowsingContext.New(configuration);
        var _document = await _context.OpenAsync(currentUrl);
        string source = null;
        if (_document.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            source = _document.ToHtml();
        }
        proxy.Stop();

        return source;
    }
    public async Task<string> GetSourceByPageIdforTor(int id,string url)
    {

        var settings = new TorSharpSettings
        {
            ZippedToolsDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "TorZipped"),
            ExtractedToolsDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "TorExtracted"),
            PrivoxyPort = 1337,
            TorSocksPort = 1338,
            TorControlPort = 1339,
            TorControlPassword = "",
            ToolRunnerType = ToolRunnerType.VirtualDesktop,
            TorStrictNodes = false,
            ReloadTools = false,
            //  EnableSecurityProtocolsForFetcher= false

        };

        // download tools
        await new TorSharpToolFetcher(settings, new HttpClient()).FetchAsync();

        // execute
        var proxy = new TorSharpProxy(settings);
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://localhost:" + settings.PrivoxyPort))
        };
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        await proxy.ConfigureAndStartAsync();
        // await proxy.GetNewIdentityAsync();

        var configuration = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader()
            .WithRequesters(httpClientHandler)
            .WithCss()
            .WithJavaScript();
        proxy.Stop();

        var _context = BrowsingContext.New(configuration);
        var _document = await _context.OpenAsync(url);
        string source = null;
        if (_document.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            source = _document.ToHtml();
        }
        proxy.Stop();

        return source;
    }
```

а вот два метода которые их вызывают

```
private async void WorckerTor()
    {
        for (int i = parserSettings.StartPoint; i <= parserSettings.EndPoint; i++)
        {
            if (!isActive)
            {
                OnCompleted?.Invoke(this);
                return;
            }
            var source = await loader.GetSourceByPageIdforTor(i);
            var domParser = new HtmlParser();

            var document = await domParser.ParseAsync(source);

            var result = parser.Parse(document);

            OnNewData?.Invoke(this, result);
        }

        OnCompleted?.Invoke(this);
        isActive = false;
    }
    private async void WorckerTor(List<string>url)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < url.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!isActive)
            {
                OnCompleted?.Invoke(this);
                return;
            }
            var source = await loader.GetSourceByPageIdforTor(i,url[i]);
            var domParser = new HtmlParser();

            var document = await domParser.ParseAsync(source);

            var result = parser.Parse(document);

            OnNewData?.Invoke(this, result);
        }

        OnCompleted?.Invoke(this);
        isActive = false;
    }
```

вот ошибка 
Значение не может быть неопределенным.
Имя параметра: handler

а когда вызываю первый раз то все норм любой из этих методов то ошибка

Comment: На какой строке падает?

Comment: на этой var source = await loader.GetSourceByPageIdforTor(i,url[i]);

Comment: А и эти методы вызываются через кнопку в винформах

Comment: ошибку нашел она была тут

Comment: var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

Comment: Но теперь другая ошибка если снять комментарий в коде

Comment: вот здесь то оно падает

Comment: await proxy.ConfigureAndStartAsync();
        // await proxy.GetNewIdentityAsync();

Comment: В общем можно было и не спрашивать, надо было добавить thread sleep